# Did the Concorde have flat plate airfoil?

Tags: wing, concorde

Did the Concorde have flat plate airfoil?
[image]

this is because in all the images I have found it appears to be a flat plate
[image]

Comment: Simple images like that are not what you should be using to base an assumption off, but even in those images you can see it is not a flat plate.

Comment: Please provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Concorde, like many other supersonic aircrafts, had very thin airfoil mainly due to aerodynamic reasons. [This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/79561/64684) gives a good overview on this topic.

Anyway the airfoil was definitely not flat i.e. neither a straight line nor without thickness. The following picture shows the central section of a Concorde and it can be seen that the airfoil there was quite thick:

[image: Concorde central section]
*Concorde central section, aft view [(source)](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b9d472_083f137014fa476da6da4275d14459c7.jpg/v1/fill/w_968,h_509,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/b9d472_083f137014fa476da6da4275d14459c7.jpg)*

Following one rib from the leading edge to the trailing edge, like the 33+51 in the next cutaway [(source)](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2e/99/9f/2e999f9bae4d0d44335ba01764d1c3c4.jpg), one can more or less unterstand the airfoil shape:

[image: Concorde cutaway]

Some reasons for the wing having a delta shape and not being flat can be found in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/94209/why-increase-chord-length-for-supersonic-aircraft-swept-vs-delta-wings/94752#94752).